# Reading directly to an object

Tags: c++

I'll go straight to the point:

I have a text file that contains a list of book names. I know how to read a text file, for example:

```
string word;
file >> word;
```

However, say I have a class called "word". Would it be possible to do:

```
word myWord;
file >> myWord;
```

If yes, how would such object have to be declared ? Would it read to the first public string it contains ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is yes, you can do `file >> myWord;`, as long
as you've defined the `>>` operator for your class:

```
std::ostream&
operator>>( std::ostream& source, Word& word )
{
    //  ...
    return source;
}
```

Several considerations:

- This operator cannot be a member; it must be a free function.
  (If it were a member, your class would be the left hand
  argument.)  If it needs to access private data, you might have
  to make it a `friend`.
- Don't forget about error checking, and the conventions of
  `istream` for errors.  If you encounter input you cannot parse
  into your class, you need to set `std::ios::failbit`.  (Of
  course, a lot of the time, you'll be delegating to previously
  defined `>>`, and if they fail, `std::ios::failbit` will already
  have been set.)

### EDIT:

As for what you should do inside the newly overloaded operator,
there are several possibilities (which can, with care, be
mixed):

- You can invoke existing `>>`, for example, for strings or
  built-in types.  This is by far the easiest, but it supposes
  that your input can easily be parsed uniquely in terms of
  existing `>>`, which is rarely the case.
- You can also use unformatted input, like `istream::get()`,
  this is most often used in parallel with the previous solution,
  to input things like separators, or other syntactical elements
  of your format.
- Or you can do revert to reading the bytes directly from the
  `streambuf`, and parse them.  This is appropriate if you have
  some totally new type, for example.  If you go this route, do
  *not* forget to set `eofbit` if you read an end of file, even if
  you can successfully parse otherwise.  If you do this, you'll
  also have to create a `sentry` object at the top of your `>>`,
  and only proceed if it is good.  (It is only in such
  `operator>>` that `std::ios::good` makes sense.  You must never
  try to read a character from the streambuf if `std::ios::good()`
  returns false, and you must set `std::ios::eofbit` anytime you
  read an EOF (which will cause all future calls to
  `std::ios::good()` to return false).  This is so essential that
  I tend to use a small wrapper object for it, and read through
  it.

In all cases, you may have to play around with the formatting
information: as a simple example, if you don't want to allow
white space within your input, but you are still using `>>`, you
should set `nows` (and restore it at the end).  Thus, most such
`>>` operators will start by saving the formatting status, and
restore it at the end.  (This is usually done by means of an
`IOSave` class, which you should have in your toolkit anyway.)
And again, if something in the input format is incorrect, you
should set `failbit`.

As a simple example, consider a `>>` for a simple `Complex`
class:

```
std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, Complex& dest )
{
    IOSave state( source );
    //      Skip leading whitespace, depending on formatting options.
    if ( (source.flags() & std::ios_base::skipws) != 0 ) {
        source >> std::ws;
    }
    source.unsetf( std::ios_base::skipws );
    std::streamsize totalWidth
        = std::max( source.width() - 3, std::streamsize(0) ); ;
    std::streamsize imagWidth = totalWidth / 2;
    std::streamsize realWidth = totalWidth - imagWidth;
    if ( source.get() != '(' ) {
        source.unget();
        source.setstate( std::ios::failbit );
    }
    double real = 0.0;
    source >> std::setw( realWidth ) >> real;
    std::numpunct<char> const& np
        = std::use_facet<std::numpunct<char>>( source.getloc() );
    if ( std::get() != (np.decimal_point() != ',' ? ',' : ';') ) {
        source.unget();
        source.setstate( std::ios::failbit );
    }
    double imag = 0.0;
    source >> std::setw( imagWidth ) >> imag;
    if ( std::peek() != ')' ) {
        source.unget();
        source.setstate( std::ios::failbit );
    }
    if ( source ) {
        dest = Complex( real, imag );
    }
    return source;
}
```

This is an extremely simplistic example.  A real `Complex`
class would, for example, also accept input in the form a+ib.
But it should give you an idea of the sort of things you have to
consider when writing such an operator.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what would be the code required inside the redefinition of the operator. Say I have a private string called "theWord" in my class Word. Would I just have to type, in the redefinition of the operator, `file >> theWord` ?

Comment: @Martin It's not redefinition, it's overloading.  (The original definitions continue to exist.)  I've edited the answer to add some of the considerations you need to keep in mind when writing your own `operator>>`, and added a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. you have to overload `>>` operator for your class `word`. You do that either as member function or a non member function.
To overload as non-member you may write:

```
fstream& operator >> (fstream& arg1,word& arg2)
{
}
```

if this function needs to access private members of `word` you may use:

```
class word{
    // somewhere in your class add this line
    friend fstream& operator >> (fstream&,word&);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do it as a member function; it must be a non-member.

Comment: @JamesKanze Of course In this case i can't.... but I just mentioned member function because user user2762087 may want to do myword<<something... (that can be done by member function)